# How can I select numbers from a space-separated list in a MySQL text field?

Tags: mysql

I'm working with an existing database that has multiple associated id codes listed in a single field, separated by spaces. For example: "21 1894 774"

I'm trying to run a query in which I pull all records containing certain numbers in this field. For example, if I search for "21", I want to match records containing "21 1894 744", "21 4", "1723 21 192", etc.

The problem is that it's also matching partials of other numbers. A query for LIKE '%21%' is matching "221", "215", "1821", etc.

I've tried various combinations with spaces ('% 21%', '%21 %', etc.) and it was better, but they still matched parts of other numbers. I also can't just do numbers surrounded by spaces because they could be in the initial position.

How can I query this table to get all records having a standalone "21" in a space-separated field? I'm stumped!

Thanks!

Comment: You can't (and not murder your database). Don't use text fields like that. That's why databases have columns.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this conditions :

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE the_text_field LIKE '21 %' OR the_text_field LIKE '% 21 %' OR the_text_field LIKE '% 21' OR the_text_field = '21'
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL support regular expressions. While it's def better to split up your numbers you can search for a match as so:

> select * from your_table where the_text_field regexp '\b21\b';

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple query, [the answer from aurel.g](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13895654/11649) is the only way; but it will do a full scan of the whole database on each query, so performace would be atrocious.

If you have to do this frecuently, better fix the database.  Add a new table with just two fields, one for a single number, and a foreign key that points to the original record where you found that number.  Then run a single scan of the whole data, creating a record for each number on that text field.  Finally, add an compound index on both columns.

after that, querying all the records with a single number would be really fast and precise.